# ConstructorInfo of a function/delegate in F#

Tags: f#, system.reflection, cil

How is it possible to get the following CIL constructor in F# (as `System.Relection.ConstructorInfo`)?

```
[mscorlib]System.Func`3<int32,int32,int32>::.ctor(object, native int)
```

I have tried the following, but I get null:

```
typeof<int * int * int>.GetConstructor([|typeof<obj> ; typeof<nativeint>|]);;
val it : System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo = <null>
```

Also, is it possible to do it dynamically? Let's say instead of 3 int types, there is a random `System.Type list`. How?

Comment: `int * int * int` is not the same as `Func<int, int, int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetDelegateType([|typeof<int> ; typeof<int> ; typeof<int>|]).GetConstructor([|typeof<obj> ; typeof<nativeint>|]).DeclaringType;;
```

The `GetDelegateType` method takes an array of types, so it can be used dynamically.